# My template can't find the views module when I call the URL function

Tags: python, django

Django noob here trying to get login working. I'm trying to load my login.html page but for some reason I get the following error:

> ImportError at /login/ No module named views

and it shows this code as triggering the error, with the error being on line 5 in the url function:

```
1   {% if form.errors %}
2   <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
3   {% endif %}
4   
5   <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
6   {% csrf_token %}
7   <table>
8   <tr>
9       <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
10      <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
11  </tr>
12  <tr>
13      <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
14      <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
15  </tr>
```

Any idea what's going on? Do I have to import views somewhere?

Comment: FIXED IT! Turns out I had screwed up my urls.py file and had a nonexistent view linked to in another url. I got rid of that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT! Turns out I had screwed up my urls.py file and had a nonexistent view linked to in another url. I got rid of that and it worked